# Jquery get latest id of element and extract the number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<div id="row1">Some content</div>
<div id="row2">Some content</div>
<div id="row3">Some content</div>
<div id="row4">Some content</div>
<div id="row7">Some content</div>
<div id="row15">Some content</div>
<div id="row915">Some content</div>
<div id="row919">Some content</div>
```

Rows are actually pulled from PHP array and now I need to extract last row's number e.g. in this case that would be 919. (so I can add +1 to row id when I use append to generate more rows via jQuery).... Any ideas ?

Comment: `parseInt(this.id.replace('row',''),10) +1 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant do what Jon have suggested you can try this:

```
var max = -Infinity;
$('div')​​.each(function () {
    var match = this.id.match(/^row([0-9]+)$/)
    if (max < match[1]) {
        max = match[1];            
    }
});

$('#row' + max).html('Max!');
​
```

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HTkkb/

The script above finds the maximum number for postfix of all div's ids and gets the element with id `row + max`

Answer (score 5):

Id suggest rather than doing this you keep a variable with the last value.  When you then append you can alter this value.  This saves getting the id and parsing it.

Answer (score 2):

assuming they're in the same div, and assuming that the row919 is the last element, you can do something like this:

```
var last_element_id = $('.parentDiv').last().attr('id');
var number = last_element_id.replace('row','');
```

Answer (score 0):

It easier to use the `data-` attribute and a class:

```
<div class="row" data-id="1">Some content</div>
<div class="row" data-id="2">Some content</div>
```

As the other answers have said, storing a variable and incrementing would be better to get the next increment. However you should still consider the data-id structure and not trying to parse it out of the id attribute which has a label wihthin it.

Comment: This is an incredibly inefficient way of approaching this problem.  Why would you loop through all elements rather than just retreiving the `last()`.

Comment: @JonTaylor I agree storing the last would be better but this answer is still helpful because the data-id structure is better than fudging the ID into the id attribute as a string. Also `last()` relies on the order being correct which I don't think would be wise.

Comment: I agree that the data- attribute can be very useful.  He also does specifically show an ordered list of items, with the greatest value at the bottom.  This leads me to assume (possibly incorrectly) that the greatest value will always be last.

Answer (score 0):

Use :last

```
alert($('div:last').attr('id').split('row')[1]);
```

Fiddle example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/tjXvG/1/)